# Wortsuche: Zeitsensitive Daten

Tags: synonym

Es gibt in der Datenverarbeitung Werte, die nur im Kontext ihrer zeitlichen Komponente interpretierbar sind. Entweder beziehen sie sich auf Zeitpunkte (bspw. Messwerte) oder sie beziehen sich auf Zeitintervalle (bspw. Durchschnittswerte).

Gibt es Worte, die diesen Sachverhalt erfassen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im Rahmen der Signalanalyse spricht man von *zeitabhängigen*, seltener auch von *zeitvarianten* Daten, Messgrößen, Signalen.